# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550

Tags: java, ora-06550

When I am trying to execute this sql statement, I am getting exception as-

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 429:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.
```

**This is the below sql String that I am executing-** Is there anything wrong with this sql? It will check whether table is there or not, if it is there then it will not create a table and if it is not there, then it will create a table.

```
    public static final String CREATE1 = "DECLARE " +
"t_count INTEGER; " +
"v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table " +DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
"(ID number(10,0), " +
"CGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"PGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"SGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"USERID VARCHAR(255), " +
"ULOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"SLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"PLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"ALOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"SITEID VARCHAR(255), " +
"PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))'; " +
"BEGIN " +
"SELECT COUNT(*) " +
"INTO t_count " +
"FROM user_tables " +
"WHERE table_name = '" +DATABASE_TABLE + "'; " +

"IF t_count = 0 THEN " +
"EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; " +
"END IF; " +
"END; ";
```

It is getting printed on the console as-

```
DECLARE t_count INTEGER; v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table LnPData((ID number(10,0), CGUID VARCHAR(255), PGUID VARCHAR(255), SGUID VARCHAR(255), USERID VARCHAR(255), ULOC VARCHAR(255), SLOC VARCHAR(255), PLOC VARCHAR(255), ALOC VARCHAR(255), SITEID VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))'; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO t_count FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'LnPData'; IF t_count = 0 THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; END IF; END;
```

Comment: Why do you have a '/'at the end of the query?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav, I just updated my question, I am getting another exception after removing that /.

Comment: When you removed the `/` you have removed the `;` as well. Can you try with the `;`?

Comment: Print out the actual query string.  If you can see what the problem with the actual query is, it is easier to fix the code that creates  it.

Comment: @StephenC, I just updated the question with the string that gets printed on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ';' after your END IF statement and run it again.

Comment: I got this error after removing `;` from END IF- `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 426:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
`

Comment: This got fixed on other thread- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771189/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-00904