# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sqlexception

I am getting this below exception-

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Below is the query that I am trying to execute-

```
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "LnPData";

public static final String CREATE_SQL = "DECLARE " +
"t_count INTEGER; " +
"v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table " +DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
"(ID number(10,0), " +
"CGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"PGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"SGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"USERID VARCHAR(255), " +
"ULOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"SLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"PLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"ALOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"SITEID VARCHAR(255), " +
"PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))'; " +
"BEGIN " +
"SELECT COUNT(*) " +
"INTO t_count " +
"FROM user_tables " +
"WHERE table_name = '" +DATABASE_TABLE + "'; " +

"IF t_count = 0 THEN " +
"EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; " +
"END IF; " +
"END; ";
```

On the console it is getting printed as-

```
DECLARE t_count INTEGER; v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table LnPData((ID number(10,0), CGUID VARCHAR(255), PGUID VARCHAR(255), SGUID VARCHAR(255), USERID VARCHAR(255), ULOC VARCHAR(255), SLOC VARCHAR(255), PLOC VARCHAR(255), ALOC VARCHAR(255), SITEID VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))'; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO t_count FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = 'LnPData'; IF t_count = 0 THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; END IF; END;
```

Comment: What is the value of `DATABASE_TABLE ` when you get this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771089/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-06550)

Comment: You've asked virtually the same question again using a different SO account name.  Don't do that!!

Comment: FWIW - I'm going to ignore both question until one or the other is closed.

Comment: Sorry about that, as previously I was getting different error and I have already posted the question so thought to put as a new question with the new errors I am getting.

Comment: @RaihanJamal - like I said, don't do that.  If you are getting a different error message, update your original question with the new details.  And delete this one!

Comment: ok. I will try to do that next time, as somebody in the forum has told me, if by fixing one thing you are getting new errors, post it as a new question. So I was following that. I apologize if I have not followed any rules.

Comment: I see a additional `(` before ID without a matching `)`. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @RaihanJamal - if you'd looked at the query string that your code is now printing out, that should have been obvious.  A bit more "proper care and attention" on your part before posting questions would save you (and us) a lot of time.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for finding it out. I will close the other thread also. As it got fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
"v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table " +DATABASE_TABLE + "(" +
"(ID number(10,0), " +
```

into

```
"v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table " +DATABASE_TABLE +
"(ID number(10,0), " +
```

and it is working. You just had one incorrect bracket.