# Create a table if doesn't exists in the Oracle (using Java)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, if-statement

I need to create an oracle table if it doesn't exists in the Oracle Database and if the table exists then don't do anything, So for that I wrote an anonymous block that works in SQL Developer if I fire that query twice or thrice I don't get any exception in sql developer. This is the below query I wrote-

```
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "LnPData";

public static final String CREATE_SQL = "DECLARE " +
"t_count INTEGER; " +
"v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'create table " +DATABASE_TABLE +
"(ID number(10,0), " +
"CGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"PGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"SGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
"USERID VARCHAR(255), " +
"ULOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"SLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"PLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"ALOC VARCHAR(255), " +
"SITEID VARCHAR(255), " +
"PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))'; " +
"BEGIN " +
"SELECT COUNT(*) " +
"INTO t_count " +
"FROM user_tables " +
"WHERE table_name = '" +DATABASE_TABLE + "'; " +

"IF t_count = 0 THEN " +
"EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql; " +
"END IF; " +
"END; ";
```

I execute the above sql query like this in my java code- First time when I run my program, table gets created, but the second time when I try to run the same program, I always get the below exception.

```
// get the connection
LnPDataConstants.DB_CONNECTION = getDBConnection();
LnPDataConstants.STATEMENT = LnPDataConstants.DB_CONNECTION.createStatement();
LnPDataConstants.STATEMENT.executeUpdate(LnPDataConstants.CREATE_SQL);
```

And I always get sql exception as-

```
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
```

Any suggestions why is it happening in the Java Code?

**P.S. I don't want to drop the table**

Updated Code:-

```
public static final String CREATE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +DATABASE_TABLE +
    "(ID number(10,0), " +
    " CGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
    " PGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
    " SGUID VARCHAR(255), " + 
    " USERID VARCHAR(255), " +
    " ULOC VARCHAR(255), " +
    " SLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
    " PLOC VARCHAR(255), " +
    " ALOC VARCHAR(255), " +
    " SITEID VARCHAR(255), " +
    " PRIMARY KEY ( ID ))";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also answered your other thread. Seems like that here you already figured out that you had one bracket to much in your query.

Your problem here is easy to solve:

If you check user_tables you will see that tables which were not created by using double quotes are always upper case - if you want a table that is case sensitive use `CREATE TABLE "tAbLeNamE"(test number)`. You select the table as "LnPData" and the table contains an entry which is LNPDATA.

Solution would be to change LnPData into upper case or just change the where clause of your query:

```
"WHERE table_name = UPPER('" +DATABASE_TABLE + "'); " +
```

Answer also belongs to your other question [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771189/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-00904/10772817#10772817).

Comment: Don't use cased-object names... it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: I just wanted to show the possibility, but you are right that case dependant tables/columns.. are a nightmare to use. The problem with his statements are that he is creating a case independant object and the check is not ignoring it.

Comment: @Eggi, Thanks for the Comment, I was not able to understand, Can you explain me again, what changes I need to make and where I need to make that, you are saying I should make changes in the table name only. Just make it UpperCase?

Comment: Yeah Thanks it got fixed. I was not able to understand your solution that you gave me why it was not working with Lowercase as automatically its get converted to uppercase right?

Comment: But my question is, If I am using lower case only, then by default oracle will convert that to upper case right? Why it was not working with lower case?

Comment: Default is that all the tables are shown as upper case. Oracle only stores case information when you double quote the information, but this leads to case sensitive tables. That means when you do CREATE TABLE "abc"(test number) and try to select from that table you will only get results when you write it exactly like that.

Answer (score 4):

Use this script in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = '<TABLE-NAME>';
  IF cnt = 0 THEN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE <TABLE-NAME>(<COLUMN-DEFINITIONS>)'; 
  END IF;
END;
```

Replacing `<TABLE-NAME>` and `<COLUMN-DEFINITIONS>` with the appropriate values.

Comment: Also, if this is for a real enterprise application, keep in mind that typically the application's user will not have rights to modify table structure (which includes creating and dropping tables).  As such, the best way to handle this in oracle is to create a stored procedure to do what you want.  That SP would be owned by a user who does have the permissions.  You'd then grant the app user permissions to execute the SP.  This acts similarly to the setuid bit in unix/linux, in that the SP runs as the user who owns it.

Comment: I updated my question with the latest code, I tried doing that I am getting an exception as- `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
`

Comment: @Matt, Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: @Oscar, I think this syntax only works with mysql I guess? Any suggestions?

Comment: Create table if exists .. this exists is not Oracle database syntex in terms of create statement .. that is why you are getting this error ..

Comment: Yes that's what I mentioned above.

Comment: @RaihanJamal I updated my answer with a solution that works in Oracle, taken from [here](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/statements/create_table)

Comment: **[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=10296aebb08a5413ebca381c3173feb7)** You have to remove semicolon inside `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly why do you need to do this at all? Your code implies that you are creating multiple identical tables all with different names. This sounds like my worst nightmare.

If I'm wrong and you're only creating one table then don't do it in code. Do it in the database first and then you're done. If I'm correct then normalise the table. Add an extra-column `username` (you already have `userid`?) or something like it and insert all your data that has this format into a single table. This table, once again, can already be created and there's no need to do it dynamically.

You might need more indexes if you normalise but it appears as though you might be missing some anyway are you really always going to have `id` when you select from this table?

---

If you feel that you really *have* to do this in the application code then, as [Matt suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771346/create-a-table-if-doesnt-exists-in-the-oracle-using-java/10771372#comment14005142_10771372), don't do this in your application code. You'll need to grant create table privileges to the schema you're operating in.

Create a user that does have these privileges and add a stored procedure to do this to that user. Then grant your application schema execute privileges on that schema.

You should also be using the [`dbms_assert` package](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2.php) to sanitize the input.

Lastly, [Eggi is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772995/458741) you need to uppercase object names, though `dbms_assert` does this by default.

You should also note that calls to `user_tables` or `all_tables` will have a performance impact. Another reason not to do it in the application.

Putting this all together you get a stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
create or replace procedure create_the_table
           ( pTableName varchar2 ) is

declare

   -- Sanitize the input.
   l_table_name := dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(pTableName);
   l_exists number;

begin

   select count(*)
     into l_exists
     from all_tables
    where owner = 'MY_APPLICATION_SCHEMA'
      and table_name = l_table_name
          ;

   if l_exists = 0 then
       execute immediate 'create table ' || l_table_name ||
                             ' ( ID number(10,0),
                                 CGUID VARCHAR(255),
                                 PGUID VARCHAR(255), 
                                 SGUID VARCHAR(255), 
                                 USERID VARCHAR(255),
                                 ULOC VARCHAR(255),
                                 SLOC VARCHAR(255),
                                 PLOC VARCHAR(255),
                                 ALOC VARCHAR(255),
                                 SITEID VARCHAR(255),
                                 PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
                               )';
      -- need to grant permissions so that we can check if this
      -- is run again.
      execute immediate 'grant select on ' || l_table_name || 
                            ' to my_application_user';
   end if;

end;
/
```

Then

```
grant execute on create_the_table to my_application_user;
```

and to call...

```
begin
   my_create_table_user.create_the_table(table_name);
end;
```

---

Basically my advice is:

1. Don't do this at all
2. If you have to do it do it in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment, I think you are confused, There is no username and password thing in this table, The name userid is for something else. According to your description, It' looks so complex if we need to check whether table exists or not.

Comment: ,As My requirement is simple, I need to run my java application, in which I need to create a table if it doesn't exists in the database, and if table is there then don't do anything.

Comment: @Raihan, my answer does that; I just also point out that you probably don't need to do it l...

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone came with similar issue, this should help:

Oracle version:

```
DECLARE
    NCOUNT NUMBER;
    V_SQL  LONG;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO NCOUNT
      FROM USER_OBJECTS
     WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'tableName';
    IF (NCOUNT <= 0) THEN
      V_SQL := ' CREATE TABLE tableName(      
      column1,       
      column2,       
      column3,       
      column4,       
      column5,            
      column6 VARCHAR2(2))';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Java version:

```
String sqlStanging = "DECLARE "
    +"NCOUNT NUMBER; "
    +"V_SQL LONG; "
    +"BEGIN "
    +"SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NCOUNT FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'tableName' ;"
        +"IF(NCOUNT <= 0) "
        +"THEN "
        +"V_SQL:=' "
        +"CREATE TABLE tableName"
        +"("
        +"      column1, "
        +"      column2, "
        +"      column3, "
        +"      column4, "
        +"      column5, "
        +"      column6 VARCHAR2(2))';"       
        +"EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL ;"
        +"END IF; "
        +"END; ";
```